# One S reboots with new CM 3.4 Kernel

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop, reboot, kernel, htc-one-s

This is something that's been bugging me ever since the 3.4 kernel was released:

**Problem:**
I am getting intermittent reboots when using any ROM which is based on the 3.4 kernel. It happens totally at random, but only when I'm actually using the phone - never when it's locked, or in my pocket.

[Here are my](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1SRtzFJxzzZckJzbDYzZXhMY28&usp=sharing) `last_kmsg` [logs](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1SRtzFJxzzZckJzbDYzZXhMY28&usp=sharing), but this is where it gets really weird - it reboots twice. Every time. Once I get the initial reboot, it reboots to the HTC screen, then immediately reboots again. So I'm not sure the last_kmsg will even be that accurate.

**Things I've Tried**

- Returning to stock RUU/upgrading/reflashing
- Not restoring apps
- Switching off Wifi
- Undervolting/Overvolting
- Different CPU Governors/Clock Speeds
- Many different ROMS
- CM10.2 Kernel & also [Bubba Kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2134535)

Would love to hear anything else I could potentially try, or other users with similar issues.

Comment: Sounds like the answer is to not user that kernel, unfortunately.

Comment: And to report a bug to the kernel maintainers.

Comment: What if it happens on multiple kernels? As I mentioned, I tried Bubba Kernel from the One S forums on XDA and experienced identical behavior. Not using the kernel is fine, I can stick with old 3.0 ROMs (until the Nexus 5 comes out!), I would just like to feed my OCD and find out *why* it's doing this